# A friendly reminder that this is meta. Questions here do not have to be questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Apparantly, somebody attempted a meta clean up. At least, I just experienced five questions in the [close vote review queue](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/review). That in itself is a tad weird considering the number of questions per day this meta experiences (which is closer to 1 per day). But it got even weirder. Take your time to check out the five questions that received close votes/flags:

- [New Design Launched](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1104)
- [New Beta Theme Launched](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/693)
- [Voting on-topic questions off-topic](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1618)
- [Some hostel booking sites we might not all know about](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430)
- [A friendly reminder that duplicates should be the same QUESTION, not different questions with similar answers](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3638)

As far as I could see, most close votes were given for *unclear.* But *none* of these meta-posts are unclear. If anything, they are ‘not a real question’ — but that does not apply to meta. For details, see [What’s Meta?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Close votes on meta should be reserved for really drastic cases:

- Posting something that wants to be a question but doesn’t include a question.
- Posting incomprehensible gibberish.
- Badmouthing the site, any users or Stack Exchange altogether.

Since nothing of this applies to the above linked posts they should be left open. In fact, some are *very* interesting from a historical point of view.

Note that leaving questions on meta unanswered or open does not affect the main site’s answered statistics.

Comment: Agree with you and +1. Ironically this question has received a close-vote as "unclear". Whoever is doing that is taking it seriously...

Comment: @mts Must.... resist...... close....voting.... this..... question....must....

Comment: @Fiksdal Please answer first, though, or Roomba will delete it ;)

Comment: @MTS LOL, some of them have three votes now :S

Comment: I think you were probably joking, but just in case: this question is not eligible for [Roomba](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) removal, since it's nice and upvoted.

Comment: @Pops Actually, I had wrong Roomba criteria in my head. I thought *closed* unanswered non-duplicate questions were also deleted after a year regardless of the vote. Good to know I was wrong there =)

Comment: @Jan, Well there was some [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239525/expand-the-roomba-scripts-to-delete-year-or-more-old-up-voted-closed-questions?rq=1) similar to that on [meta.se]. Still, only if the question had < 2 upvotes.

Comment: Once again, someone has voted to close this question as unclear, along with like a dozen other questions from meta, most of which are quite clear.